# Question about the proof of non-complete statistic

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

[image]

---

***Definition 6.2.21*** (from *Statistical Inference 2ed by George Casella*)

Let $f(t|\theta )$ be a family of pdfs or pmfs for a statistic $T(\mathbf{X})$. The family of probability distributions is called complete if $\mathbb {E}_{\theta } g(T) = 0$ for all $\theta$  implies $\mathbb{P}_{\theta }(g(T) = 0) = 1 $ for all $\theta$. Equivalently,$T(\mathbf{X})$ is called *a complete statistic*.

---

Let $U=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i,V=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$.
I think from ***Definition 6.2.21***, In order to prove that $T=(U,V)$ is not complete, at first, we need to find $ g_{\theta}(u,v)$-the pdf of $\left (U,V \right )$, And then to construct a function $g(u,v)=2u^2-(n+1)v\not\equiv 0$ such that $$\mathbb {E}_{\theta } g(T) = \iint_{\mathbf{R}^2}g(u,v)\cdot g_{\theta}(u,v)dudv=0,\text{for all} \quad \theta\in \Theta .$$

But in the ***Example 12***,$$g(x_{1},\cdots,x_{n})=2(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i})^{2}-(n+1)\sum_{j=1}^{n}x^{2}_{j};$$
$$g_{\theta}(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left [ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\theta}\exp\left\{-\frac{(x_i-\theta)^2}{2\theta^2}\right\} \right ];$$
$$\mathbb {E}_{\theta } g\left\{T(\mathbf{X}) \right\}$$

$$=\int\cdots\int_{\mathbf{R}^n} g(x_{1},\cdots,x_{n})\cdot g_{\theta}(x_1,\cdots,x_n)dx_1\cdots dx_n=
\mathbb {E}_{\theta }\left\{2\left ( \sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}\right)^2-(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}^2  \right\}.$$

I don't understand this could prove that $T$ is not complete.Where is the $g_{\theta}(u,v)?$ Maybe we should verifty that $$\mathbb {E}_{\theta } g(T)=\mathbb{E}_{\theta } g\left\{T(\mathbf{X}) \right\} \quad \text{for all} \quad \theta\in \Theta.$$

Comment: The authors are claiming that $E_{\theta}T(X_1,\dots,X_n) = 0$ for every $\theta$. However, $T(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is not almost surely 0, implying $T$ is not a complete statistic.